# Projection of a function $f$ in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ on a subspace $\mathcal{D}\subset\mathcal{H}$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, projection

I am reading a paper on functional data analysis and they use a Hilbert space as living space for their functions. Then they defined a "dictionary" $\mathcal{D}\subset\mathcal{H}$ where the elements (functions) of this set are noted $d$, then they define the inner product $\langle , \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}$ on this Hilbert space. Here is my problem :

When they consider $d\in\mathcal{D}$ and $f\in\mathcal{H}$ and they look at $\langle f, d\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}$, they say that this is the projection of $f$ on $\mathcal{D}$ but I don't see why.

From my knowledge, this inner product can at best describes the coordinates of the projection of $f$ on $\mathcal{D}$ and it requires that there exists an orthonormal basis on this subspace, something that is not mentionned in the paper.

Did I miss some properties of infinite dimensional vector space ?

Comment: All Hilbert spaces have orthonormal bases. But the concept of the projection of $f$ onto $\mathcal D$ does not require an orthonormal basis to define. The projection is the vector in $\mathcal D$ that is closest to $f$. If $d$ is a vector of unit length, then $\langle f, d\rangle$ is the *length* of the projection of $f$ onto *the line of $d$* (not $\mathcal D$, unless there are more restrictions on $d$ than just $d \in \mathcal D$).

Comment: Thank you Paul. When I was saying that it requires an orthonormal basis it is to say that $\langle f, d\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}$ is the coordinates of the projection of $f$ on $D$, of course we can define a projection without orthonomality assumption I agree. When use the term "line" for the unit vector $d$ I don't really see the picture if $d$ is also a function ? Thank you a lot for your time.

Comment: Don't get hung up on it happening to be a function. It is a vector in a vector space, and that is all you need to know about it to understand the terminology. We define vector spaces in a myriad of ways. Most of them are function spaces (in a sense even the vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ are functions, just with the domain $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$). But the vectors still can be thought of as objects with a magnitude and a direction. The only thing that differs is how many dimensions that direction can point in. The line of $d$ is the 1-dimensional subspace $\{\alpha d\mid \alpha \in \Bbb R\}$

Comment: Oh right, thank you very much! I have in mind that the notion of vector makes sense for many objects different from those we can represent (vectors in the plane typically) but I had not taken the time to think about the notion of "line". When you say that the only thing that differs is how many dimensions that direction can point in, are you referring to the different values ​​that the function can take ? Sorry to ask you questions but what you say is interesting and I want to be sure to understand ! Thank you a lot

Comment: $\langle f,d\rangle$ is not a projection. If $d$ is a unit vector, then $\langle f,d\rangle d$ is a projection onto the subspace spanned by the single vector $d$. But $\langle f,d\rangle$ is not a projection because a projection is a vector, not a scalar. Whatever terminology you were taught, it was not that $\langle f,d\rangle$ is projection because no Math prof would say that.

Comment: Please make an effort to read the post, at no time do I say that it is a projection, on the contrary I question this terminology which I find false (which you confirm). Thank you.

Comment: @coboy : Read your second paragraph, "they say that this is the projection..." I addressed that correctly.